# CakePHP 2.7.11 PHPUnit Coretests - testEnableCrypto

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

we are currently setting up our automatic testing for one of our CakePHP Applications. First of we are trying the Cake Core tests with a fresh CakePHP 2.7.11. (Don't worry as soon as the tests are all up and running, we will be upgrading ;-) ) Unfortunatly the CakeSocketTest::testEnableCrypto() fails everythim with the following message:

```
SocketException: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the Testservers setup. But I am not sure where to start my search.

If anybody has a hint what I could do it would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

```
public function testEnableCrypto() {
    // testing on ssl server
    $this->_connectSocketToSslTls();
    $this->assertTrue($this->Socket->enableCrypto('sslv3', 'client'));
    $this->Socket->disconnect();

    // testing on tls server
    $this->_connectSocketToSslTls();
    $this->assertTrue($this->Socket->enableCrypto('tls', 'client'));
    $this->Socket->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: A simple search on google would have revealed that this is just a matter of the configuration. So just set the right version. I guess this will do it in Cake 2 http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/source-class-CakeSocket.html#433

Comment: Unfortunatly no. Or maybe I don't understand the whole thing. But the coretests (written by CakePHP not me) explictly call these specific versions. I've updated my post with the actuall testcase.